# The problem for conditional expectation.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> The joint probability density function for random variables $X$, $Y$ is given by
> $$f(x, y)=\begin{cases}
> 2xy  & \text{if } 0\leq x\leq 2y\leq 2 \\ 0 &  \text{otherwise}
>  & 
> \end{cases}.$$
> When the conditional expectation of $X$ is $E(Y | X=aY)=\frac{3}{10}$, what is the real number $a(>1/2)$?

My first solution is
$$f(y \mid x=ay)=\frac{f(ay, y)}{f_{x}(ay)}=\frac{2ay^2}{\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{a}}2ay^2 dy}=3a^3y^2$$
$$\frac{3}{10}=E(Y\mid X=aY)=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{a}} 3a^3y^3 dy=\frac{3}{4a} \Rightarrow a=\frac{5}{2}\,.$$

My second solution is

Let $Z=\frac{X}{Y}, \;  W=Y$.
Then, $X=YZ, \: \: Y=W, \;$, the Jacobian is $W$ and
$g(z,w)=f(wz, w)w=2zw^3 \; (\frac{1}{2}\leq z\leq \frac{1}{w}, \; 0\leq w\leq 2)$
$$g(w \mid z=a)=\frac{g(a, w)}{g_{Z}(a)}=\frac{2aw^3}{\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{a}}2aw^3 dw}=4a^4w^3$$
$$\frac{3}{10}=E(W\mid Z=a)=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{a}} 4a^4w^4 dw=\frac{4}{5a} \Rightarrow a=\frac{8}{3}\,.$$

Why do I get two different values of $a$?

Comment: The question seeks $E(X | Y=aX)$ but your working is for $E(Y | X=ay)$

Comment: @MathLover sorry! It was modified.

Comment: There's an answer to [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4182311/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-with-conditional-probability-expectation/4658584#4658584) which I think can help sort out some of the confusion here.